# why does "UInt64[] arr=new UInt64[UInt64.MaxValue];" throw exception?

Tags: c#

Why does following code throw exception **"Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."** ?

```
UInt64[] arr=new UInt64[UInt64.MaxValue];
```

Comment: You really want to allocate an 18 exabyte array...?

Comment: I just wish to create max length integer array containing value as an index for each array element. My array would be [0][1][2][3][4]..[1000]....[Max] .Here I need to find the value of max.

Comment: @Greg, it's 18 x 10^18 elements * 8 bytes per element, or in other words exactly 147,573,952,589,676,412,928 bytes (147 exabytes, or according to Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte, about 8 months of traffic across the entire internet).

Comment: @Ron - Oops, I was calculating for a `byte[]` not a `long[]`, so yeah it's 8 times bigger. Either way, it's still a preposterous amount of data!

Comment: Whatever problem you're trying to solve, this is the wrong way to go about it. Why don't you post another question asking about a different approach to the problem?

Answer (score 7):

I guess because totally `8 * UInt64.MaxValue` bytes is requested to be allocated, and this multiplication obviously overflows a 64-bit register.

Comment: This will never be allocated because you even if you had that much memory, C# has internal limits on the length of arrays.  When you specify a legitimate value for the length, but don't have the memory, you get an `Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown` error message.

Answer (score 7):

Because indexers only take Int32 values.  You can do

```
UInt64[] arr=new UInt64[Int32.MaxValue];
```

But thats the limit.

EDIT: Technically you can index an array with value structures that can theoretically be higher than Int32.MaxValue (because you can index an array with a long or a uint for example), however, you will run into that runtime error when the value exceeds Int32.MaxValue.

Comment: UInt64[] arr1 = new UInt64[Int32.MaxValue] throws the same error but UInt64[] arr1 = new UInt64[Int16.MaxValue] does not.

Answer (score 2):

Because

a) all object are limited to 2GB in .NET
  b) You don't have 64 PetaBytes of memory to spend

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's documentation, with framework .NET 4.5 these limitations apply:

- The maximum number of elements in an array is UInt32.MaxValue.
- The maximum index in any single dimension is 2,147,483,591 (0x7FFFFFC7) for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures, and 2,146,435,071 (0X7FEFFFFF) for other types.
- The maximum size for strings and other non-array objects is unchanged